# How can we improve voting

Tags: discussion, voting

I asked a question a few days ago at [Can I pray in this shirt?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/17907/7864) and like it says in the Help centre I made sure to ask for Hanafi references in the question so I would not get answers that were not Hanafi answers. But the answer on the question gave me references that were not Hanafi rather it had a Saudi Arabia fatwa which is Hanbali?  And this answer has upvotes and a positive score?

How can we improve the voting here because if answers are being upvoted that are nothing even what I asked for how can anybody trust this site?

Answer (score 1):

Drop a comment illustrating why it doesn't answer the question. [**Vote appropriately**](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/982), and **flag**.

If you have high enough rep vote to delete, provided it's not positively voted. Bring it to meta if you think it needs a louder broadcast and that it needs community engagement.